# reload or source /etc/enviornment file from golang code

Tags: bash, ubuntu, go, sh

I have tried the source command from my go code,after i write env variables to the /etc/enviornment file.

Below is the sample code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    address := "localhost:9090"
    file, err := os.OpenFile("/etc/environment", os.O_RDWR, 0644)
    defer file.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    input, err := ioutil.ReadAll(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    lines := strings.Split(string(input), "\n")

    for i, line := range lines {
        if strings.Contains(line, "HTTP_PROXY") {
            lines[i] = "HTTP_PROXY=" + address
        } else {
            if i == (len(lines) - 1) {
                lines[i] = "HTTP_PROXY=" + address
            }
        }
    }
    output := strings.Join(lines, "\n")
    err = ioutil.WriteFile("/etc/environment", []byte(output), 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "source /etc/environment")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err = cmd.Run()
    fmt.Println("cmd=================>", cmd, err)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

It dint return any error

But when i try to check my HTTP_PROXY  in using `env | grep -i proxy` I dont see it getting reflected.
I can only see the change is done when it restart the system or run the source command again from another terminal.

All i want is to change the os proxy from the go code without restarting the system.

If there is any other approach to this please mention that as well.

Answer (score 2):

> But when i try to check my HTTP_PROXY in using env | grep -i proxy I dont see it getting reflected.

It's because the environment is reloaded only in a new session (or if you manually sourced it). Otherwise, the current shell's variables remain the same.

> > ```
> > cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "source /etc/environment")
> > ```

This runs the command in a subshell and the changes in it don't affect the parent shell. So once the process exits, the changes disappear.

In fact, it's not at all possible to change environment variables that can affect parent process as changes would only affect the current/child processes - thus can't change the parent process' environment.

Comment: cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "set -a  source /etc/environment; set +a")   would this help?

Comment: No. Once the `bash -c ..` process exits, the changes are gone. After your program ran (that modified /etc/environment), you can `source` it yourself. But can't done via your program itself.

Comment: okay,so once I have written the env variable to the file,The only option I have is to restart the system or run the source command myself?If yes,the are there any approach which I could follow to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, those are some options. But restart isn't needed. New shell sessions will be sufficient. Even `source'ing (in the current shell) will not help much as the existing processes that have been running already won't get this new environment variable (it'll useful only for the new processes started from that session). Once you change the variable, you simply need to restart the required services.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "source /etc/environment")` this will load env variables but limited only to session created by the 'bash' command there, hence will be no effect to other session.

What you can do per my 2 cents:

1. Change the above code only to change the file
2. Create a simple bash script to run your go file or execute compiled one and then sourcing the /etc/env file

Bash file could be something like this

```
#! /bin/bash
go run your_change_envfile.go
source /etc/environment
```

Then just run the bash file, don't forget to chmod+x on your bash so it can be executed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a common enough problem that we all have come up with kludge workarounds like restarting processes, or wrapper scripts around binaries.

Taking a different perspective and suggesting `godotenv`: https://github.com/joho/godotenv
(I don't think I can do a better job summarizing godotenv than the project's own README)

Essentially godotenv parses environment vars and makes them active in the *current* go process. Yeah, it's parsing. But if you have processes you don't want to script-wrap and restart, it's the answer.

godotenv has a sizable user base, so it handling any parsing edge cases better than a DIY attempt.